# Load Script in AssetBundle at Runtime (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime, .net-assembly, assets, assetbundle

I try to load scripts in AssetBundle in runtime. I created an asset bundle that contain a prefab. This prefab has some components. The scripts of these components are not in the bundle (Because of a bundle cant contain scripts) . When I download/load the bundle, prefab can not load the scripts because of these scripts are not in the project folder(not compiled). So I compile (create dll file) these scripts and put the dll file into bundle (as a bytes file). Now I can access the dll file (Assembly.load) and I can addComponent to a gameObject. That is ok. I know that I need to load the dll before creating the prefab. But when I create a prefab, still prefab can not load the script. I can not add a new component to the created object because component has some referances. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Is this about a .NET assembly?  It's clearly not about assembly language (text version of machine code), but I took a guess at what tag to replace it with.

Comment: yeah. I compiled the script in visual Studio (.Net3.5) No problem whit compiling script or creation dll

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so please edit your question to contain the error(s)

Comment: There is no error.  I dont know how I load the dll/scripts. Prefab cant find script/references. I  load the dll using System.Reflection.Assembly.Load but as I said prefab can not find it.